# i have a syntax error help me

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace TRIGGER SET_HOLDER_IN_ONLINE_DOC
BEFORE  INSERT ON tasks 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
id, repl_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF :new.holder_role_id = 10 THEN
    SELECT user_id, repl_user_id  INTO id, repl_id  FROM roles 
      WHERE roles.id=10;
      IF repl_id = 0 THEN
        :new.holder_user_id := id;
      ELSE
          WHILE repl_id > 0
          LOOP
              SELECT user_id, repl_user_id  INTO id, repl_id  FROM roles 
                 WHERE user_id=repl_id;
          END LOOP;
          :new.holder_user_id := id;
      END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Error(7,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:     constant exception <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare two variables together as you can in some other languages, so this:

```
DECLARE 
id, repl_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
```

should be:

```
DECLARE 
id NUMBER:
repl_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
```